# Failed To Launch IE Driver Using Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, exception, ie

I am trying to execute the selenium web driver script in IE browser but I got this error? can any one provide the solution.

**Code :**

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;

public class demo3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\work\\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver= new InternetExplorerDriver();     
        driver.get("http://www.msn.com");
        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
        System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl());




    }

}
```

**Getting Error in console and have also attached the screenshot :**

> Aug 12, 2018 8:52:17 PM org.openqa.selenium.os.OsProcess checkForError
>   SEVERE: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Execution failed
>   (Exit value: -559038737. Caused by java.io.IOException: Cannot run
>   program "C:\work\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe" (in directory "."):
>   CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application)
>   Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException:
>   Timed out waiting for driver server to start. Build info: version:
>   '3.13.0', revision: '2f0d292', time: '2018-06-25T15:32:14.902Z' System
>   info: host: 'GITANJALI-PC', ip: '192.168.0.12', os.name: 'Windows 7',
>   os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '10.0.2' Driver
>   info: driver.version: InternetExplorerDriver  at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:193)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:179)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:79)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:548)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:212)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.run(InternetExplorerDriver.java:221)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.(InternetExplorerDriver.java:213)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.(InternetExplorerDriver.java:150)
>     at demo3.main(demo3.java:10) Caused by:
>   org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker$TimeoutException: Timed out waiting
>   for [http://localhost:42885/status] to be available after 20007 ms    at
>   org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:100)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:188)
>     ... 8 more Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException     at
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:204)    at
>   com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.callWithTimeout(SimpleTimeLimiter.java:156)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:75)
>     ... 9 more

Comment: can you please edit it a bit so that we can read it?

Comment: You probably are trying to run the application compiled for 64-bit Windows under 32-bit Windows.

Answer (score 2):

MicrosoftWebDriver.exe is the Edge driver, not IE driver. As others have mentioned the IE driver is called IEDriverServer.exe.

As an example of a launcher for IE:

```java
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\DriverFiles\\IE\\x32\\IEDriverServer.exe");

// custom stuff IE needs in order to work (some only needed for Win10+)
DesiredCapabilities ieCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
ieCapabilities.setCapability("nativeEvents", false);
ieCapabilities.setCapability("unexpectedAlertBehaviour", "accept");
ieCapabilities.setCapability("ignoreProtectedModeSettings", true);
ieCapabilities.setCapability("disable-popup-blocking", true);
ieCapabilities.setCapability("enablePersistentHover", true);
ieCapabilities.setCapability("ignoreZoomSetting", true);

// deprecated but working
driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(ieCapabilities);


// Set browser defaults (maximise, clear cookies, set timeouts)
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

Change the following line as

```
   System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\work\\IEDriverServer.exe");
```

The file name is IEDriverServer.exe and not MicrosoftWebDriver.exe. Check the path for IE driver.